# How to modify my code that works with an ACCESS database to work with an SQL database

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a code running to import CSV files into a Access database. However now I have access to a SQL server and want to use the same code if possible, but no idea what to change to adapt the code

I have a set of running code which uses a connection string I add parameters and it works.

````
$connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=$inputDatabase" 
 $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectionString)
 $conn.Open()
 $cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()

 $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Tabl1]([date],[zone],[location],[Plugin ID],[CVE],[CVSS],[Risk],[Host],[Protocol],[Port],[Name])
         VALUES(@date, @zone, @location, @PluginID, @CVE, @CVSS, @Risk,@Host,@Protocol,@Port,@Name)"```
````

```
        [void]$cmd.Parameters.Add('@date',      [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType]::DateTime)
        [void]$cmd.Parameters.Add('@zone',      [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType]::VarChar)
```

both code snippets above show how I set up my connection string, and a quick example of how 2 values are set with their corresponding variable type, it is not the whole code . but the snippets I know I need to change to make it work with an SQL server, the main issue being that  i dont know which $connectionstring to use with an SQL server, or for example how do I make it so the data source points to the SQL server network address and uses windows authentication.

And on the second code snippet, which type of format do I use, I knwo the variable types but I assume that if I change from ace.oledb.12 , i should change the oldebtype segment.  The SQL server is on SQL 13.0.5426

Comment: Your code should be fine on any database that supports square braces for delimiting identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update your connection string. Assuming you're using Windows authentication:

```
$ConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI' -f $ServerInstanceName, $DatabaseName
```

And you should use the built-in SQL Server client class, `System.Net.SqlClient`, instead of OLEDB classes.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString
```

And you'll want to update your parameter types:

```
[void]$cmd.Parameters.Add('@date',      [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)
[void]$cmd.Parameters.Add('@zone',      [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar)
```

Everything else should be more or less identical.

---

Here's a working PowerShell script that connects to an SQL Server database, fetches data, and fills a data table:

```
$SqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student_Id = @student_id'
$ConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True' -f $SqlServer, $Database

$SqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $ConnectionString
$SqlCommand = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand -ArgumentList $SqlQuery, $SqlConnection
$SqlCommand.Parameters.Add('@student_id', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 10).Value = $Student_Id

$DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable -ArgumentList 'Student'

try {
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SqlDataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    $DataTable.Load($SqlDataReader)
}
finally {
    $SqlConnection.Close()
}
$DataTable
```

Comment: what about the table? i see that you specify the serverinstancename and database name, but what about the table?

Comment: @VictorJMytre What about it? It's the `$DataTable` variable. I instance an empty DataTable and then call the Load method with the SqlDataReader to load the data into it. The last line would output the table. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: I forgot to add, the sql table already exists, I am trying to import into an existing table.

I also ran into another problem with the data type datetime, the value for date is : 8/28/2019 9:13   for example, and it seems I am getting an error regarding the usage of datetime and the way that the date is formatted on my csv file

Comment: I see my issue, my code is different, I am adding an existing CSV . and my code above sets the object, I then use a foreach loop so I can go through each row of a csv and add the parameters. so in my code I have no idea where to put my table information

Comment: @VictorJMytre My example code is a SELECT statement. Your code is an INSERT statement. It was intended to be a simple example so you could see how similar it is, not code you could copy and paste. The core of your code should not be significantly different other than the classes used.

Comment: @VictorJMytre  You will need to convert your strings to C# DateTimes with `Get-Date` before you assign the value to the parameter, or else you can use a string format for datetimes that SQL Server expects like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`.

Comment: Thank you! I realized my issues and fixed the code, yet it was a bit slow I ended up using dbatools. Thanks a lot as you provided me with enough answers to continue on my own!.